# C++ Sudoku solver for 16x16. Not sure why it is not working as expected?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a 16x16 sudoku solver. I have built a 9x9 that works relatively well. The strategy I am trying to use is elimination and then guessing, however my code is not working. I believe it is a logical error. I am a student that is just learning how to program so please try not to get too technical. I really hope someone can help. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

const int N = 16;
array<array<int, N>, N> board;
array<array<set<int>, N>, N> possibilities;
vector<pair<int, int>> guesses;

void eliminate_possibilities();

int char_to_int(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

char int_to_char(int i) {
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
        return '0' + i;
    } else if (i >= 10 && i <= 15) {
        return 'A' + i - 10;
    } else {
        return '0';
    }
}

bool solve() {
    int min_possibilities = N + 1;
    pair<int, int> next_cell = {-1, -1};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (possibilities[i][j].size() < min_possibilities) {
                min_possibilities = possibilities[i][j].size();
                next_cell = {i, j};
            }
        }
    }
    if (next_cell.first == -1 && next_cell.second == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    int row = next_cell.first;
    int col = next_cell.second;
    for (int val : possibilities[row][col]) {
        board[row][col] = val;
        guesses.emplace_back(row, col);
        eliminate_possibilities();
        if (solve()) {
            return true;
        }
        board[row][col] = 0;
        guesses.pop_back();
    }
    return false;
}

void eliminate_possibilities() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            set<int> &p = possibilities[i][j];
            p.clear();
            for (int val = 1; val <= N; val++) {
                bool valid = true;
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                    if (board[i][k] == val || board[k][j] == val) {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                int boxRowStart = (i / 4) * 4;
                int boxColStart = (j / 4) * 4;
                for (int r = boxRowStart; r < boxRowStart + 4; r++) {
                    for (int c = boxColStart; c < boxColStart + 4; c++) {
                        if (board[r][c] == val) {
                            valid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (valid) {
                    p.insert(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << int_to_char(board[i][j]) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cin >> c;
            board[i][j] = char_to_int(c);
        }
    }

    eliminate_possibilities();
    if (!solve()) {
        cout << "No Solution" << endl;
    } else {
        print_board();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some sample inputs and outputs:
Input 01:

```
C 0 8 9 0 6 F 0 4 0 0 B E 0 D 1
0 0 5 0 0 8 0 0 0 D 0 G B 0 0 3
B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 4 8 0 0
0 0 6 0 0 0 A G 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9
0 5 0 0 C 9 0 0 0 F 0 8 A 4 0 0
0 0 F 4 8 D 0 0 0 0 G E C 0 0 5
A G 0 8 0 0 6 E 0 4 0 0 0 0 9 0
6 0 0 E 0 G 4 0 3 5 B 9 D 0 1 0
0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 C 0 0 0 0 1 E 6
0 0 E 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 G 0 F 0
0 0 B 0 A 0 G 0 0 7 8 0 0 0 C D
0 0 0 D 0 B C 0 0 0 0 F 8 3 5 0
8 B 0 A 0 C 2 0 0 0 6 0 0 7 4 0
E 0 D F G 0 8 0 B 0 0 0 0 9 0 0
0 0 0 0 F 0 B 0 0 E 0 0 6 0 0 0
0 7 4 6 1 A D 0 0 C 0 0 F 0 0 0
```

Output 01:

```
C A 8 9 2 6 F 5 4 3 7 B E G D 1
1 F 5 2 4 8 E 7 9 D A G B C 6 3
B E G 7 D 3 9 C 1 6 2 5 4 8 A F
4 D 6 3 B 1 A G E 8 F C 2 5 7 9
D 5 7 B C 9 3 2 6 F 1 8 A 4 G E
9 3 F 4 8 D 1 B 7 A G E C 6 2 5
A G 1 8 5 F 6 E D 4 C 2 3 B 9 7
6 2 C E 7 G 4 A 3 5 B 9 D F 1 8
F 9 A G 3 2 5 8 C B D 4 7 1 E 6
5 8 E C 6 4 7 D 2 9 3 1 G A F B
3 4 B 1 A E G F 5 7 8 6 9 2 C D
7 6 2 D 9 B C 1 A G E F 8 3 5 4
8 B 9 A E C 2 3 F 1 6 D 5 7 4 G
E C D F G 5 8 6 B 2 4 7 1 9 3 A
2 1 3 5 F 7 B 4 G E 9 A 6 D 8 C
G 7 4 6 1 A D 9 8 C 5 3 F E B 2
```

My output:

```
C A 8 9 2 6 F 5 4 3 7 B E 0 D 1
1 F 5 2 4 8 E 7 9 D A 0 B C 6 3
B E 0 7 D 3 9 C 1 6 2 5 4 8 A F
4 D 6 3 B 1 A 0 E 8 F C 2 5 7 9
D 5 7 B C 9 3 2 6 F 1 8 A 4 0 E
9 3 F 4 8 D 1 B 7 A 0 E C 6 2 5
A 0 1 8 5 F 6 E D 4 C 2 3 B 9 7
6 2 C E 7 0 4 A 3 5 B 9 D F 1 8
F 9 A 0 3 2 5 8 C B D 4 7 1 E 6
5 8 E C 6 4 7 D 2 9 3 1 0 A F B
3 4 B 1 A E 0 F 5 7 8 6 9 2 C D
7 6 2 D 9 B C 1 A 0 E F 8 3 5 4
8 B 9 A E C 2 3 F 1 6 D 5 7 4 0
E C D F 0 5 8 6 B 2 4 7 1 9 3 A
2 1 3 5 F 7 B 4 0 E 9 A 6 D 8 C
0 7 4 6 1 A D 9 8 C 5 3 F E B 2
```

Input 02:

```
0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 E 0 2
7 0 B 0 0 0 0 0 A 0 2 D 0 F 0 5
1 0 G E 3 B 2 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 D
0 2 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0 8 B 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 G 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 B 1 C E 0 0 0 8 0 5 7 0 A 0 0
F 0 0 G 0 0 0 0 1 0 9 2 0 0 6 4
0 0 5 0 2 0 0 7 0 0 0 4 8 1 0 B
0 0 4 0 0 0 0 8 0 A 0 B C 0 0 1
0 0 8 6 0 E 0 3 D 0 0 0 0 9 0 0
0 0 D F B G 5 4 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 A
0 G 0 9 C 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 B 0 8 0
0 0 0 D 6 0 0 0 0 1 F G 0 0 7 0
E 0 0 A 0 C B 0 9 0 0 0 0 5 0 0
0 0 3 0 5 0 0 0 0 B 0 0 D 0 E 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 G 3 E C 0 A 0 0 0
```

Output 02:

```
D A F 8 7 9 4 5 B C 6 1 G E 3 2
7 9 B 4 G 8 E C A 3 2 D 6 F 1 5
1 C G E 3 B 2 6 5 9 8 F 7 4 A D
3 2 6 5 F A D 1 G 4 7 E 9 8 B C
2 8 9 7 1 4 G A C 6 B 3 F D 5 E
4 B 1 C E 6 3 D 8 F 5 7 2 A 9 G
F E A G 8 5 C B 1 D 9 2 3 7 6 4
6 D 5 3 2 F 9 7 E G A 4 8 1 C B
5 3 4 2 9 7 6 8 F A E B C G D 1
B 7 8 6 A E 1 3 D 2 G C 5 9 4 F
C 1 D F B G 5 4 7 8 3 9 E 6 2 A
A G E 9 C D F 2 4 5 1 6 B 3 8 7
8 5 C D 6 3 A E 2 1 F G 4 B 7 9
E 6 2 A 4 C B F 9 7 D 8 1 5 G 3
G F 3 1 5 2 7 9 6 B 4 A D C E 8
9 4 7 B D 1 8 G 3 E C 5 A 2 F 6
```

My output:

```
"No Solution"
```

Looking forward to any responses.
Thank you

I think it has something to do with the choosing of a guess or maybe the stopping criteria.

Comment: Generally questions like "Here's all my code, what's wrong with it?" are frowned upon. What have you done to try to tackle the problem yourself? Rather than look at a 16x16 case, maybe simplify it to a 4x4 example and walk through the code yourself.

Comment: [OT]: possibly `char int_to_char(unsigned int i) { assert(i < 16); return "0123456789ABCDEF"[i]; }` (and that fixes EBCDIC :-) )

Comment: FYI, programs rarely "...work as expected."  I recommend small board size, and using a debugger.  Try what I call "Murphy's Law Programming":  expect that it doesn't work, plan for those "unlisted" requirements.

Comment: We see 'G' appears in output, whereas you limit to 0-9A-F ...

Comment: Replacing all occurrences of `arr[i]` with `arr.at(i)` (assuming `arr` is a `std::array` or `std::vector`) will cause any out-of-bounds lookup to throw an exception. That might help narrow down some problems.

Comment: *however my code is not working* -- The problem with simply posting code just saying "something is wrong" will lead to downvotes.  Programming is much more than writing code, seeing it doesn't work, and then report to StackOverflow (or anywhere else) that your code is not working.  Debugging your own code is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  At the very least, you should be able to point out *where* the problem is in the code.  Fixing the code is a different issue, but if you wrote the code, you must be able to identify where the problem is.

Comment: Also, I suggest you hard-code one of those sample inputs into the program instead of using `cin` statements in a loop.  No one is going to sit at their keyboard and type in the input every time they want to debug your program.

Comment: For testing purposes, I recommend against using `std::cin` to enter new puzzles. Instead, call a function such as `assign_sample_puzzle` or `read_puzzle_from_disk`. That way, you don't have to waste time entering the puzzle over and over again during testing.

Comment: @Jarod42 `0` indicates that the value is unknown ...

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: You print 16 values; with 0 as unknown/empty, so you have only 15 values...